# Can I place the table's vertical scrollbar on right side, and make the horizontal scrollbar start from the right side as well?

Tags: html, css

I want my table to be RTL table, so that if the table contents are too wide and needs horizontal scrolling, it will show the table from its rightmost column.

I also want to have a vertical scrollbar if the table is too long, but that the scrollbar will be on the right side.

To add the scrollbar, I wrapped the table in container and gave it `max-width`.

I managed to make the horizontal scrollbar load on the right using `direction: rtl`, however it also moves the vertical scrollbar to the left:

```css
.table-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
        <td>!!!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
        <td>!!!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
        <td>!!!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
        <td>!!!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Can I have both on the right side?

Comment: talking strictly on how to style the scrollbar is a very tricky task... there are ways to hide them (despite being engaged) in very browser specific ways and then add regular html elements working on their behalf. It's a viable option especially if you don't need the scroll thumb to control directly with the mouse the visible portion. But before addressing that solution, did you consider to just leave the default direction and via JS set `content.scrollLeft = content.scrollWidth - content.clientWidth;`?

Comment: I said that because `direction: rtl` is aimed at content expected to be read from right to left.. and in such cases, the horizontal scrollbar is expected to be on the left side. Things like those are expected to be left alone and managed by the browser to ensure accessibility features remain responsability of the browser/OS as configured by the user. But yet if you just need to scroll to the far right the content of an element, it's enough to just set its `scrollLeft` property